# Why does a fever flucturate when sick?

Tags: fever

I'm just getting over an illness now which came with a fever.  I couldn't help but notice that the fever fluctuated drastically over the course of the illness, with me switching between number of blankets/layers of clothes constantly.

I understand the importance of the fever in the immune response and why it occurs, but I'm curious why it would fluctuate so drastically.  I would have expected it to stay at a certain constant 'high' for much of the illness, and only start to drop as I fought off the illness.  I'm curious why the fever appeared to instead constantly vary throughout the illness.